# On building a compatible pipeline for astrometry using both Gaia or Vera-Rubin's data

Tags: data-analysis, astrometry, gaia, vera-c-rubin-observatory, data-pipeline

As the title states, I'm considering building a pipeline for astrometry to analyze Gaia and Vera Rubin's data.

As, being honest, I have little experience with astrometry, I'm not sure if this is (or not) reinventing the wheel in some sense, but to this point I still think it sounds useful as a side project of what I'm doing now.

Considering the latter, it's always helpful to know if these kind of work has already been done and can be found, e.g., in GitHub, Research or package's docs (e.g., [pygaia](https://pypi.org/project/pygaia/)). Another, more specific, question that comes to my mind has to do with: how feasible is for a pipeline made for one telescope could fit for another? Or more usually when a team starts to work for a pipeline the solution is done for specific data sets and it's fine to accept this constrain?

Maybe a related or more direct question is: how similar or different, for astrometry, will the data be, comparing Gaia's mission and Vera Rubin's LSST telescope.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking since you wouldn't have access to the raw data of either project but the basically the pipelines would be very different. The [Gaia astrometric solution](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2021/05/aa39709-20/aa39709-20.html) has to iteratively globally solve for the positions of all the sources along with the orientation of the spacecraft and their changes with time, which runs into millions of params. Rubin can just use the Gaia catalog to solve for positions; a few 10s of params. Gaia is also ~2500x more accurate and must consider many more effects

Comment: BTW the LSST [astrometry measurement module](https://github.com/lsst/meas_astrom) is available in Github for reference (it relies on a lot of the rest of the LSST Science Pipelines modules so isn't trivial to get running but there is [documentation](https://pipelines.lsst.io/))

Comment: I assume that you want to build a general-purpose astrometry pipeline for analysing the two datasets. But as already mentioned in the comments, these two are vastly different datasets with different science goals. Gaia astrometry is considered to be very precise. For any general-purpose astrometry, you may use astrometry.net through the astroquery package if you want to perform astrometry on any available frames.